# System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() Does Not Work Under NUnit Console

Tags: maven, nunit

When I put

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test Output");
```

in my NUnit tests, nothing comes out on the console. Is it supposed to come out on the console, or does this end up in some mysterious place in the Windows System Logs? I have looked at the system logs, but cannot find anything.

```
[INFO]  | NUnit-Console version 2.6.3.13283
[INFO]  | Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
[INFO]  | Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
[INFO]  | Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
[INFO]  | All Rights Reserved.
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  | Runtime Environment -
[INFO]  |    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
[INFO]  |   CLR Version: 2.0.50727.8000 ( Net 3.5 )
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  | ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
[INFO]  | Execution Runtime: net-3.5
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  | Tests run: 2, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.148235177410271 seconds
[INFO]  |   Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  +--[ DONE ]
```

I am invoking NUnit from Maven: could that be causing some sort of problem?

Interestingly enough, under JUnit, System.out.println() works just fine, as you would expect.

Comment: Try `System.Console.WriteLine("Test Output")`

Comment: Same results, no visible output from the test code :-(

Comment: It could be that Maven is using the [`-output=`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3) switch to send console output to a file.  Try just running your test with the NUnit console runner and see if you see the output.  Should be as easy as `nunit-console.exe YourAssembly.dll`

Comment: OK, when I run nunit-console I do see the output from the tests. I will post a better solution when I figure out what Maven/NPanday is doing and how to fix it. Thanks muchly Patrick

Comment: Feel free to post your configuration for running NUnit, more people can help that way.